# Combining like rows, and concatenating associated data. Street Index assistance

Tags: excel

So I've searched and searched and can't find any solutions to my issue.

I'm creating a street index for a gis map. I created a grid and joined it to my centerlines. My table looks as follows after trimming down the columns:

```
Name      | Grid  
ACOMA CT  | 10B  
ACOMA ST  | 10B  
ACOMA ST  | 6B  
ACOMA ST  | 7B  
ACOMA ST  | 9B  
ACOMA WAY | 10B  
ACOMA WAY | 9B  
ADAMS CIR | 4D  
ADAMS CIR | 7D  
ADAMS CT  | 5D  
ADAMS CT  | 7D  
ADAMS CT  | 9D  
ADAMS PL  | 7D
```

And so forth. 3800 entries like this.

How can I combine all the similar streets (ACOMA ST) and have the Grid cell show all the values (10B, 6B, 7B, 9B). 
Example of how I'd like it to look:

```
ACOMA CT  | 10B  
ACOMA ST  | 10B, 6B, 7B, 9B  
ACOMA WAY | 10B, 9B  
ADAMS CIR | 4D, 7D  
ADAMS CT  | 5D, 7D, 9D  
ADAMS PL  | 7D
```

I know how to do this by hand (=CONCATENATE) but I'd like to have a formula that I can run on all 3800 entries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `Name` is in `A1` try in C2:

```
=IF(A1=A2,C1&","&B2,B2)
```

and in D2:

```
=IF(A2<>A3,"*","")
```

and copy both down to suit.

Select all, Copy and Paste Special, Values over the top. Filter for other than `*` in ColumnD and delete rows. Remove filter and delete ColumnD.

Comment: I like the approach of this answer however it seems that it does depend on the fact that records with the same `Name` are contiguous. The sample data in Q does show this but the asker doesn't provide that this ordering is indicative of all 3800 rows. Might be worthwhile to clarify this and to provide steps to ensure this i.e. sorting `Name` column first.

Comment: This is awesome. Thanks a lot for posting this. Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If your indicated output format is just an suggestion, you can consider using PivotTable to accomplish this similarly as shown below:

[image]

Why this is useful approach over others is because it is simpler and less complex to maintain and it doesn't require repeating intricate steps to reproduce. Once you set the range of the data source you only need to refresh the table to recalculate the results. Furthermore it doesn't depend on your data being sorted or grouped by `Name` i.e. rows that contain `ACOMA CT` could be discontiguous.

Ideally Excel users should leverage existing functionality as much as possible. If this is suitable I would be happy to provide additional instructions if you're unsure about PivotTables.